# UserControl OnLoad event has stopped firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a user control that I add to my main form when it is loaded. I have not touched my main form's code. But I noticed that my User Control's `OnLoad()` event is skipped and not fired anymore.

This is the my User Control's designer code bit in which the user control subscribers to the `Load` event:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
this.AutoSize = true;
this.Controls.Add(this.listviewMappings);
this.Controls.Add(this.lblMessage);
this.Controls.Add(this.btnAddMapping);
this.Controls.Add(this.comboTo);
this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxFrom);
this.Controls.Add(this.lblTo);
this.Controls.Add(this.lblFrom);
this.Controls.Add(this.lblAddNewMapping);
this.Controls.Add(this.lblCurrentMappings);
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
this.Name = "UserControlMappingsFilesVsContacts";
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(940, 420);
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.UserControlMappingsFilesVsContacts_Load);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.listviewMappings)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```

and this is my load event that is not fired:

```
private void UserControlMappingsFilesVsContacts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    this.RefreshPropertiesCombo();
    this.RefreshMappings();
}
```

Note that, my User Control's constructor is run and the `InitializeComponent()` method displays the controls. Also I have enabled the `Common Library Runtime Exceptions` to be thrown but I receive none.

Comment: Is there any chance you're unhooking that event handler elsewhere in your code?

Comment: How did you verify that the load event handler isn't called?  Did you put a breakpoint in that method?

Comment: @adv12 yes I have put a breakpoint there. I also have a label which is supposed to be set to `string.Empty` on load and that does not work either.

Comment: @adv12 that's very unlikely.

Comment: Can you try moving the subscription to after the line with `EndInit()`? I wonder if it's firing `Load()` before the initialization is finalized.

Comment: So the event handler doesn't get called, even the first time you show your main form?

Comment: @DrewJordan no luck.

Comment: @adv12 no it has stopped firing. because I put a breakpoint there and nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe the source is somehow not in sync with the executable and the breakpoint isn't where it appears in the code?  (Just wild guesses here...)  Does a full rebuild help?

Comment: Do you have the InitializeComponents() call in the usercontrol constructor?

Comment: Along the same lines as @adv12, since this is a weird situation... I would try restarting VS, and also try removing the subscription from the designer, and adding it manually into the constructor. It *seems* like everything should be fine.

Comment: @Gusman yes. `InitializeComponents()` is the last line on my constructor.

Comment: last line? hmmm, usually it should be the first (usually), try to put it before anything.

Comment: @Gusman nothing changes whether I put it on the first or the last line. This is a real strange error.

Comment: Does the constructor really execute?

Comment: @Gusman yes the constructor is executed. I remove the `Load` event from the user control, rebuild the project and then add a new `Load` event. But it's as if it's cursed. The event is completely ignored.

Comment: Only two things come to my mind: 1-The control is not inside a form, then the load event doesn't executes (maybe are you creating the control in code and not adding it to a form?). 2-There is an exception just before or on the first line of the Load event, whenever an exception is thrown at the Load event it skips the rest of the code but no exception is thrown (vey bad Microsoft's decission)

Comment: Did you override the `OnLoad` method in your `UserControl`? If so make sure you call `base.OnLoad()` there, otherwise the event is not fired. Also, if you _didn't_ override it, you could try overriding it anyway and put a breakpoint there and on the place where you attach the event handler, see which is called first.